# Can't comment in a thread started from an unregistered account

Tags: support, comments

Last night I started a thread. Then today I created an account which the very same nickname I used when posting my question. I got some comments which I'd like to answer, but it turns out that I cannot - I need 50 reputation to do so, even though I was the original poster, which, as I read in the FAQ, entitles me to comment regardless. Is that a bug or did I get something wrong? Any chance to fix that?  If that's of any help, the thread I'm talking about is this one:

[Thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/accuracy-of-numerical-methods-in-finding-eigenvalues)

Comment: You must be using the same account in order to freely comment on your own posts.  Creating another account with the same name doesn't change that.

Comment: And how do I access the unregistered account I used? I couldn't answer my question before I registered this one either. I haven't deleted any cookies recently. Is there any way of accessing that account? Or do I have to use 'answer' to let people know I can't comment and continue the discussion in the comment section under that answer?

Comment: Use the [Contact Us](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/contact) form to request an account merge with the other account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments it's the account you use that needs to be the same for you to be able to comment on any answer to your own question. If you create a second account then that one has the same rights as any other random account and can only comment when it has earned 50 points.

What you need to do is create a **registered** account and then ask the team, via the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form, to merge the unregistered account with the registered one. Once you have done that your question will become "owned" by the registered account and you'll be able to comment on the answers and accept an answer (should one be satisfactory).

Comment: It's all fine now, I did as you both suggested - thanks a lot!